# vectors- proof using dot product

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider two non-zero perpendicular vectors u and v:

(b) Show that the vectors x = u + λv and w = u − λv
(where
λ
∈
ℝ
is a scalar) have the same length.
(c) Find the value of
λ^2
if
x
and
w
are also perpendicular.

kind of stuck here...for a (a) i got |x|= sqrt[(a+λd)^2 + (b+λe)^2 + (c+λf)^2], where a,b,c,d,e,f are pro numerals for vetors u and v i.e. i let u = ai +bj + ck and v = di + ej+ck

Thanks!

Comment: Numerically expressing the vectors is usually more trouble than it's worth. Hint: $\vec{a} \cdot ( \vec{b} + \vec{c} ) = \vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} + \vec{a} \cdot \vec{c}$, and $\| \vec{a} \| = \vec{a} \cdot \vec{a}$.

Comment: @auriga123: Welcome to MSE! It really helps to format your questions using MathJax (see FAQ). Also, it helps to at least detail what you have tried on the problem and where the confusion may lie. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part, consider that

$$
|\mathbf{x}|^2 = |\mathbf{u}|^2+2\mathbf{u}\cdot\lambda\mathbf{v}+\lambda^2|\mathbf{v}|^2
$$
But $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ are perpendicular, so $\mathbf{u\cdot v}=0$, and

$$
|\mathbf{x}|^2 = |\mathbf{u}|^2+\lambda^2|\mathbf{v}|^2
$$
Similarly,
$$
|\mathbf{w}|^2 = |\mathbf{u}|^2-2\mathbf{u}\cdot\lambda\mathbf{v}+\lambda^2|\mathbf{v}|^2 = |\mathbf{u}|^2+\lambda^2|\mathbf{v}|^2
$$
Therefore, $|\mathbf{x}|^2=|\mathbf{w}|^2$ and the lengths are the same.

For the second part, I'll just give a hint:

$$
\mathbf{x\cdot w} = |\mathbf{u}|^2 + \mathbf{u}\cdot\lambda\mathbf{v}-\lambda\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{u} - \lambda^2|\mathbf{v}|^2 = 0
$$
Solve for $\lambda$.

Comment: THank you so much ! really appreciate you help and easy logic....now i understand how to go on about doing these kind of questions :)

Answer (score 0):

$\|x\|^2 = \langle x ,x \rangle = \langle u+ \lambda v  , u+ \lambda v \rangle = \|u\|^2 + 2 \lambda \langle u ,v \rangle + \lambda^2 \|v\|^2$. Since $u,v$ are perpendicular, we have $\|x\|^2 = \|u\|^2 + \lambda^2 \|v\|^2$.

Similarly, $\|w\|^2 = \langle w ,w \rangle = \langle u- \lambda v  , u- \lambda v \rangle = \|u\|^2 - 2 \lambda \langle u ,v \rangle + \lambda^2 \|v\|^2 = \|u\|^2 + \lambda^2 \|v\|^2$.

Hence the lengths are equal.

If $x,w$ are perpendicular, we have $\langle x ,w \rangle = 0$, expanding as above gives: $\langle x ,w \rangle = \langle u+ \lambda v  , u- \lambda v \rangle = \|u\|^2 -  \lambda^2 \|v\|^2$, from which we get $\lambda^2 = \frac{\|u\|^2}{\|v\|^2}$.